# Get a previous file version in git tower

Tags: git-tower

I need to get a previous file version in git tower,

I mean get the **full** code present inside file as it was 1 week ago (before a lot of edits from other users), and copy it somewhere on my desktop.

I already located that version of the file in tower, and if right click on it I get this menu:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

After you identified the commit, click on it to make it active. 
In the commit details (middle pane), choose *Tree* in the menu in the upper right corner. Locate the file you need in the tree and right-click it. Then choose *Export* to save it to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next command being abdcef the hash of the commit you want to recover

```
git checkout abdcef /path_to_file
```